# How to parse xml from net?

Tags: android

Please see the link http://buydeals.in/api.getDealsGeo/xml/?lat=40.6137&lon=-80.0547 . How to parse this link?. I am new to XML parsing and don't know the algorithm for parsing. Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an example project you can build here: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser